# Automatically update PDF as I write .Rnw file with knitr

Tags: r, pdf, latex, textmate, knitr

I'm writing a .Rnw file in TextMate when using knitr to convert this file to a .tex file, then converting the .tex file a PDF. I'm wondering if there are any tools available that will automate this process, ie everytime anything updates in the .Rnw file, the PDF also updates? Using knitr to combine R and LaTeX code is great, but I think the conversion process to PDF takes up a lot of time, especially if changes to the .Rnw file are small but need to be cross-checked in the PDF file everytime they are made.

Comment: It would seem you would need `cache = TRUE` in knitr (chunks). Upon compilation, this will update only "changed" chunks (a change is a matter of definition).

Comment: I think what I'm hoping for is more ambitious than `cache = TRUE`. I want the PDF to update automatically, without having to manually compile the .Rnw and .tex files

Comment: Take a look at any of the build automation tools, e.g. [makefile](http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/) or [gradle](http://www.gradle.org/)

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Linux use [inotifywait](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki) for that. Most distributions have the package *inotify-tools*

Then do something like

```
while inotifywait -e close_write myfile.Rnw; do compile_myfile.sh; done
```

or

```
while inotifywait -e delete_self myfile.Rnw; do compile_myfile.sh; done
```

It depends on how your editor actually saves files. Just try and read the man page.

You have to write `compile_myfile.sh` of course to compile the .Rnw to .pdf - but I guess you know the commands.